# How to create Public and protected Navbar links in Material UI with react and redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

guys so I'm trying to create a navbar with a set of private navbar links that will be only visible to the user when they log in. Otherwise, the only pages before logging in with a JWT are the register and login page and the register page is set as the '/' directory.

I would like the user prior to registering to see only the /Register, and /Login pages

if the user is logged in I want them to see the /Balance, /Deposit, /Withdraw, and Alldata page

I can't seem to figure this out on MUI can someone help me out, please? Here is my code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import AdbIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Adb';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { logout, reset } from '../features/auth/authSlice'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'




const Navigation = () => {
  
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)


  const pages = ['Register', 'Login', 'Deposit', 'Withdraw', 'Alldata'];


  const settings = ['Balance', 'Logout'];
  
  const onLogout = () => {
    dispatch(logout())
    dispatch(reset())
    navigate('/')
  }


  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState(null);
  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState(null);

  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleOpenUserMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };

  const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <AdbIcon sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' }, mr: 1 }} />
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href="/"
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.3rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            LOGO
          </Typography>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElNav}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
              onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
              }}
            >
              {pages.map((page) => (
                <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">
                    <Link to={`/${page}`}> 
                      {page}
                    </Link>  
                  </Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ) 

              )}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
          <AdbIcon sx={{ display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' }, mr: 1 }} />
          <Typography
            variant="h5"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href=""
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },
              flexGrow: 1,
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.3rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            BADBANK
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
            {pages.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
                >
                <Link to={`/${page}`}> 
                     {page}
                </Link>  
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
            <Tooltip title="Open settings">
              <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Menu
              sx={{ mt: '45px' }}
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElUser}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
              onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
            >
              {settings.map((setting) => (
                <MenuItem 
                key={setting} 
                onClick={onLogout}>
                
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a conditional statement on links array based on auth state

```
const pages = user ? ['Deposit', 'Withdraw', 'Alldata'] : ['Register', 'Login'];
```